# Edit word document embedded in a web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, winforms, sharepoint, ms-office

I need to implement in my web application the ability to create and edit a word documents. I see that the [Ultra Office](http://www.ultrashareware.com/Ultra-Office-Control.htm) package can do this, but my application is not windows based (Angular/Javascript+Scala on the back end). Is there an alternative solution? Is it possible to embed Sharepoint?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a WYSIWYG HTML editor and only convert it to MS Word format as needed. The closest you can get to Word in a web browser is Microsoft's Office Online, and it still lacks all of the features of Word.

Comment: What about having an ActiveX object embedded in the web page?

Comment: Adding an ActiveX is, security wise, an absolute no-no. Most modern browser even stopped supporting ActiveX objects so you will most likely lose a part of your audience.